# Magento 2: get order id on success page

Tags: magento2, php, sales-order

I'm trying to put the conversion event snippet into my success page, but I dont know how do I get the order_id to pass with.

My code is:

```
gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': '...',
        'transaction_id': '<?= $orderId ?>'
    });
```

But how do I define the `$orderId` on success page's head tag?

Comment: You want to pass order id in js file?

Comment: it's a phtml file with js script on it

Comment: let me know if you'll face any issue in solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have custom block then, just inject this below code in your block file :

### Construct Method

```
protected $checkoutSessionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\SessionFactory $checkoutSessionFactory 
){
    $this->checkoutSessionFactory = $checkoutSessionFactory;
}

public function checkoutSessionObj()
{
    return $this->checkoutSessionFactory->create();
}
```

After that, you can use this below code in your phtml file.

```
$orderObj = $block->checkoutSessionObj()->getLastRealOrder();
echo $orderObj->getEntityId(); //Entity Id
echo $orderObj->getIncrementId(); //Increment Id
```

### Object Manager Method :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getLastRealOrder();
echo $orderObj->getEntityId(); //Entity Id
echo $orderObj->getIncrementId(); //Increment Id
```

**Note : Don't use object manager directly**